# Angular embedding template from derived component to base component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-directive

I'm trying to understand how to use Angular composition. My situation is that I have a list of questions that each have a type. Based on that type part of the template changes. Ideally I was thinking I needed a base component with it's own template that would have an `ng-content` placeholder where the derived component would inject it's specific content into the parent component. Do I need to create the child templates as directives? Here's what I have so far.

outer template

```
<questionnaire>
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" [ngSwitch]="question.type">
        <question-type-a *ngSwitchCase="'A'" [question]="question"</question-type-a>
        <question-type-a *ngSwitchCase="'B'" [question]="question"</question-type-b>
        <question-type-a *ngSwitchCase="'C'" [question]="question"</question-type-c>
    </div>
</questionnaire>
```

question component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html'
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() question: IQuestion;

  constructor() { }
```

question.component.html template

```
<div>
    <ng-container #details></ng-container>
    <button>do something</button>
</div>
```

question-type-a template

```
<ng-template #mydetails>
   <button>Answer Question</button>
</ng-template>
```

question-type-a component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'question-type-a',
  templateUrl: './question-type-a.html'
})
export class QuestionTypeAComponent extends QuestionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("details", { read: ViewContainerRef }) details: 
ViewContainerRef;
   @ViewChild("mydetails") mydetails: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() question: IQuestion;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let view = this.yesnotdetails.createEmbeddedView(null);
    this.details.insert(view);
  }
}
```

In the end I am trying to understand how to get #mydetails from the derived component into the #details container in the base component. Clearly this is not the correct approach. I've been searching on embedded templates and derived components but I can't quite wrap my head around how to accomplish what I'm trying to do or find an example that matches what I think i need. What's the right way to build this so I can have a main template and a derived template?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [content projection](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691) in angular.

Example:

**QuestionContainerComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'question-container',
  template: `
    <div class="question-container">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div>`,  
})
export class QuestionContainerComponent  {}
```

**QuestionComponent**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'question',
  template: `
    <div class="question">
      {{model}}
    <div>`,  
})
export class QuestionComponent  {
  @Input() model : any;
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <question-container>
      <div *ngFor="let question of questions" [ngSwitch]="question.type">
        <question *ngSwitchCase="1" [model]="question.value"></question>
        <question *ngSwitchCase="2" [model]="question.value"></question>
      </div>  
    </question-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    questions: any[] = [
      { type: 1, value: 'My question 01'},
      { type: 2, value: 'My question 02'},
      { type: 3, value: 'My question 02'},
      { type: 4, value: 'My question 02'},
    ];
}
```